# Read empty parquet file with FetchParquet processor and retrieve the schema

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, parquet

The Nifi [FetchParquet](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-parquet-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.FetchParquet/index.html) processor does not inherit the schema from Parquet file without Records. We try to convert the parquet file to csv with the [CSVRecordSetWriter](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVRecordSetWriter/index.html) by inheriting the schema.

We do a "create table as select" CTAS on hive and write the result into parquet files in HDFS. Then we try to read those files with the Nifi FetchParquet processor.

This works fine for files that contain records.
Files that do not contain records will fail, even though the schema is included in the metadata of the parquet file. For consistency it should be possible to convert this into a csv file with only the header as content.

Any suggestions how this can be handled in a consistent way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external schema registry to do this.

https://hortonworks.com/open-source/schema-registry/

However this is quite the manual effort unless you can write a script to extract from the metadata, then add to SchemaRegistry and similarly ensure that the NiFi flow has the correct variable to reel in the right schema.

Alternatively, make sure to check the CSVRecordSetWriter settings so you are actually telling the file to check for headers.